# Gremlin code to find 1 vertex with specific property

Tags: gremlin

I want to return a node where the node has a property as a specific uuid and I just want to return one of them (there could be several matches).

`g.V().where('application_uuid', eq(application_uuid).next()`

Would the above query return all the nodes? How do I just return 1?

I also want to get the property map of this node. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would just do:

```
g.V().has('application_uuid', application_uuid).next()
```

but even better would be the signature that includes the vertex label (if you can):

```
g.V().has('vlabel', 'application_uuid', application_uuid).next()
```

Perhaps going a bit further if you explicitly need just one you could:

```
g.V().has('vlabel', 'application_uuid', application_uuid).limit(1).next()
```

so that both the graph provider and/or Gremlin Server know your intent is to only `next()` back one result. In that way, you may save some extra network traffic/processing.

Comment: So if the vertex had other properties besides `application_uuid`, this would still match right? Like the property passed to `has` just has to be one of several properties on the existing vertex right?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic query. You should read more about gremlin. I can suggest [Practical Gremlin](http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html) book.
As for your query, you can use `has` to filter by property, and `limit` to get specific number of results:

```
g.V().has('application_uuid', application_uuid).limit(1).next()
```

Running your query without the `limit` will also return a single result since the query result is an iterator. Using `toList()` will return all results in an array.

Comment: So if the vertex had other properties besides `application_uuid`, this would still match right? Like the property passed to `has` just has to be one of several properties on the existing vertex right?

Comment: Right. Please accept the answer if you find it helpful.